# How to perform arithmetic operations on an xml file in awk

Tags: xml, bash, awk, sed

If there are columns in a file you can easily do arithmetic operations. But if you want to read the an xml file, modify a particular tag arithmetically and then write the changes to the same.

Take for example the snippet below:

```
<product>
  <programname>Bla</programname>
  <programurl>blah.com</programurl>
  <catalogname>beep it</catalogname>
  <lastupdated>ridiculous</lastupdated>
  <name>Another pile of garbage</name>
  <keywords>whatever</keywords>
  <description>random</description>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <price>3.99</price>
  <buyurl>deeplyrandomurl.html</buyurl>
</product>
<product>
  <programname>nowheretownthing</programname>
  <programurl>sick.com</programurl>
  <catalogname>beep it</catalogname>
  <lastupdated>ridiculous</lastupdated>
  <name>Another pile of garbage</name>
  <keywords>whatever</keywords>
  <description>random</description>
  <currency>USD</currency>
  <price>10.78</price>
  <buyurl>deeplyrandomurl.html</buyurl>
</product>
```

Let there be many such `<product>` blocks in a bulky xml file. How will we modify each `<price>` subtags and write the changes to the file? Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you want to replace the value of price tag? Show an sample xml file with two product tags.

Comment: `modify a particular tag arithmetically` clarify clearly. Post sample output.

Comment: There you go...these are two product tags now

Comment: want to replace price tag value with what?

Comment: Yes replace 10.78 with 21.56 (10.78*2 = 21.56) and in the same way 3.99

Comment: Use a real XML parser. Awk will -always- be just a hack for XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `p.awk` as a `awk` program:

**p.awk**

```
{
  if ($L ~ /\<price>/)
  {
    split($L,a,">");
    split(a[2],b,"<");
    gsub(">.*<",">"2*b[1]"<",$L);
  }
  print $L
}
```

then

```
cat file | awk -f p.awk
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sed here's a possible solution. You write the following code in a bash script (let's say script.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

tr '\n' ';' < XMLFILE > TEMPFILE
c=1

for i in $(sed -n 's/.*price>\([0-9]*\.*[0-9]*\)<\/price>/\1/p' XMLFILE); do
    i=$(awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN{print (i*2)}')
    sed -i "s/<price>\([0-9]*\.*[0-9]*\)<\/price>/<price>$i<\/price>/$c" TEMPFILE
    c=$((c+1))
done

tr ';' '\n' < TEMPFILE > XMLFILE
rm -f TEMPFILE
```

Then you just execute the script:

```
./script.sh
```